Langflow file storage
I'm working on a custom component for Langflow which is going to receive an image from the chat input, modify it with the help of an API call, then pass it on to be part of the chat output from an OpenAI model.
In the message structure from the chat input, I can see the name of the file, made up of the session ID + original file name. However, I do not know where it is stored, and I need to know how to access it, so that I can send it to the external model through the API call.
I am running Langflow both on Datastax and locally. Where are files uploaded in the chat input stored? And how can I access them?
I have tried to open the file using Image.open(filename), however it then adds /app/... to the filename on Datastax, and 'C:/Data/...' locally, neither of which contain the file.
